# Android studio dumping hprof file into the project folder

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, gradlew

After updating gradle version to 3.3 (I'm not sure if this effects anything at all) but sometimes, my build takes about 30 min. and I see a file called "java_pid1160.hprof" file in my project's main package when the build complete or cancelled. The file is around 2-5~ GB. My CPU works insanely while this happens and I see increased fan activity. I know that hprof files are the java memory dumps but since Android Studio has memory monitor and also dumping the memory to a hprof file, it is really hard to find anything useful. Anyone else having this problem?

Answer (score 7):

I'd say your build went out of memory and Gradle has by default `-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError` set, so you get a heap dump in case of out of memory. I wonder that you don't also get the OOM displayed though.

You should try to increase the max memory that you grant to your build. Add e. g.

```
org.gradle.jvmargs = -Xmx2g -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
```

to your projects `gradle.properties` file (create it if not present, it has to be in the root projects directory) to increase the max memory.

It could of course also be that you have a memory leak in your build scripts, so that the memory cumulates over runs. If you kill the gradle daemon with `gradlew --stop` and then this behavior comes back only after a few builds, then you probably have a memory leak that you should investigate and fix. If it fails immediately after stopping the daemon, your build might simply need more memory. If the problem is a memory leak, increasing the max memory will only help temporarily and you will get the same behavior, just after more builds than before.

Comment: Yea after a while it gives GC Out of memory error. I remember increasing the heap size, gonna check it out and post it here.