# .hprof files in android studio project root directory

Tags: android, android-studio, heap-dump

In my android studio project root directory that I work on it, some files with huge size(2.6 G) are created with a name like

> java_pid8965.hprof

I deleted these files, but after a while are created again when I build project
I searched about it and I found these files are for java heap dump
My questions are:

- why these files are created?
- How can I prevent creating these files?

Comment: It's possible you have less memory ( RAM ). I accidentally committed 3 gigs to git once LOL.

Comment: Found good answer in the link below [android-studio-dumping-hprof-file-into-the-project-folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44824442/android-studio-dumping-hprof-file-into-the-project-folder)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android studio dumping hprof file into the project folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44824442/android-studio-dumping-hprof-file-into-the-project-folder)