# Out of memory : Java Heap Size Error on a project forked from GitHub

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I am working on a client app and I have made forked on GitHub, it's a very big app, and from the previous 3 days, I am getting errors out of memory: Java heap size. I tried all troubleshoots, increase heap size also, check the same code on a 16GB laptop, and there also got the same error.

Error log:-

```
    Cause 1: org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkExecutionException: A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$RunnableWrapperWorkAction
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkItemExecution.waitForCompletion(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:339)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.lambda$waitForItemsAndGatherFailures$2(DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.java:131)
    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:31)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withoutLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:341)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withoutLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:326)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.waitForItemsAndGatherFailures(DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.java:127)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.waitForItemsAndGatherFailures(DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.java:89)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.waitForAll(DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.java:79)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.waitForCompletion(DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.java:67)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor.await(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:247)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$WorkerExecutorAdapter.await(Workers.kt:109)
    at com.android.ide.common.resources.MergeWriter.end(MergeWriter.java:48)
    at com.android.ide.common.resources.MergedResourceWriter.end(MergedResourceWriter.java:199)
    at com.android.ide.common.resources.DataMerger.mergeData(DataMerger.java:292)
    at com.android.ide.common.resources.ResourceMerger.mergeData(ResourceMerger.java:385)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.MergeResources.lambda$doFullTaskAction$1(MergeResources.java:339)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Blocks.recordSpan(Blocks.java:51)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.MergeResources.doFullTaskAction(MergeResources.java:335)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.MergeResources.doTaskAction(MergeResources.java:394)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.NewIncrementalTask$taskAction$$inlined$recordTaskAction$1.invoke(BaseTask.kt:69)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Blocks.recordSpan(Blocks.java:51)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.NewIncrementalTask.taskAction(NewIncrementalTask.kt:47)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor846.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:104)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalInputsTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalInputsTaskAction.java:32)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AbstractIncrementalTaskAction.execute(AbstractIncrementalTaskAction.java:25)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:29)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution$3.run(TaskExecution.java:242)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.executeAction(TaskExecution.java:227)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.executeActions(TaskExecution.java:210)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.executeWithPreviousOutputFiles(TaskExecution.java:193)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.execute(TaskExecution.java:171)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.executeInternal(ExecuteStep.java:89)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.access$000(ExecuteStep.java:40)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep$1.call(ExecuteStep.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep$1.call(ExecuteStep.java:50)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:50)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:40)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemovePreviousOutputsStep.execute(RemovePreviousOutputsStep.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemovePreviousOutputsStep.execute(RemovePreviousOutputsStep.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:48)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CancelExecutionStep.execute(CancelExecutionStep.java:41)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.executeWithoutTimeout(TimeoutStep.java:74)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.execute(TimeoutStep.java:55)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:51)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.java:61)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.java:42)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.execute(BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.java:60)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.execute(BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.java:27)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.executeWithoutCache(BuildCacheStep.java:180)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.lambda$execute$1(BuildCacheStep.java:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.Either$Right.fold(Either.java:175)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.caching.CachingState.fold(CachingState.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.execute(BuildCacheStep.java:73)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.execute(BuildCacheStep.java:48)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:25)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:22)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.executeBecause(SkipUpToDateStep.java:110)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.lambda$execute$2(SkipUpToDateStep.java:56)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:369)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:56)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:73)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:44)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:37)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:27)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:89)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:50)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ValidateStep.execute(ValidateStep.java:114)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ValidateStep.execute(ValidateStep.java:57)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:76)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:50)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.executeWithNoEmptySources(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:249)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:86)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.execute(RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.java:32)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.execute(RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.java:21)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.java:31)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.lambda$execute$0(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:40)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution$4.withWorkspace(TaskExecution.java:287)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.execute(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:40)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.execute(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:30)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentityCacheStep.execute(IdentityCacheStep.java:37)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentityCacheStep.execute(IdentityCacheStep.java:27)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentifyStep.execute(IdentifyStep.java:44)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentifyStep.execute(IdentifyStep.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultExecutionEngine$1.execute(DefaultExecutionEngine.java:76)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:144)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:133)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:74)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:333)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:320)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:313)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:299)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.lambda$run$0(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:143)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:227)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:218)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:140)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.desktop/java.awt.image.DataBufferInt.<init>(DataBufferInt.java:75)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.image.Raster.createPackedRaster(Raster.java:467)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.image.DirectColorModel.createCompatibleWritableRaster(DirectColorModel.java:1032)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.image.BufferedImage.<init>(BufferedImage.java:333)
    at com.android.ide.common.util.AssetUtil.newArgbBufferedImage(AssetUtil.java:51)
    at com.android.ide.common.vectordrawable.VdPreview.getPreviewFromVectorTree(VdPreview.java:264)
    at com.android.ide.common.vectordrawable.VdPreview.getPreviewFromVectorXml(VdPreview.java:199)
    at com.android.builder.png.VectorDrawableRenderer.generateFile(VectorDrawableRenderer.java:275)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.MergeResources$MergeResourcesVectorDrawableRenderer.generateFile(MergeResources.java:721)
    at com.android.ide.common.resources.MergedResourceWriter$FileGenerationWorkAction.run(MergedResourceWriter.java:409)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$RunnableWrapperWorkAction.run(Workers.kt:181)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.profile.ProfileAwareWorkAction.execute(ProfileAwareWorkAction.kt:74)
```

and one thing which i notice is everytime this error occurs, some type of .hprof files of around 1-2 gb each are formed in that android project folder, i tried deleting them and then clean and rebuild , then again this thing happends.

[image]

[image]

this is my gradle memory configuration and i have even change it to maximum also and different also , still getting that same issue :-

[image]
[image]
**

UPDATE 1-->One strange thing which I notice is that, when I created a zip of this same project and then try to do Gradle build, I am able to do it without any issue.

Which means issue occurring only on GitHub one, so please guide me how to solve this issue, as GitHub one is very important.
**

Comment: Have you seen/tried: [Android studio dumping hprof file into the project folder](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44824442/295004)

Comment: yes I have already tried that

Comment: You should probably [edit your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71977025/edit) to include what gradle memory configuration you are using, and if you tried building just from the command line. FYI: [Expiring Daemon because JVM heap space is exhausted](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56075455/295004)

Comment: yes i have updated plz check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I am happy to tell everyone, after a long hit and trial for last 3-4 days, I found a perfect solution, these are my updated settings which helped me to solve my java heap issue:-

gradle.properties --:

```
signing.element.storePath=pathTo.keystore
signing.element.storePassword=Secret
signing.element.keyId=Secret
vector.debugPrivateData=false
org.gradle.parallel=true
android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true
org.gradle.vfs.watch=true
signing.element.keyPassword=Secret
vector.httpLogLevel=BASIC
org.gradle.configureondemand=true
org.gradle.daemon=true

org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx12800m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -XX:MaxHeapSize=256m
```

and most important thing, VM options, go to help --> edit custom VM options:-

```
-Xms2024m
-Xmx12800m
-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=512m
-XX:+UseCompressedOops
```